# Which dual monitor hub that can switch between MacOS and Windows should I use

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, hub, usb-c, macos

I'd like to be able to switch between a Windows and a MacOS laptop using the same 2 external monitors (for the sake of this conversation, we'll say they are fairly new Dell 27 inch monitors, let me know if other properties are important I guess) plugged into a USB hub.

I thought this would just be a matter of choosing a type C hub with the right inputs but after reading some it seems this may not be the case? I want to extend not mirror across the screens, also. Can anyone make a hub/port recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this one from amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Monitor-Display-Docking-Charging/dp/B08BYJYC5K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BYJYC5K)

According to the description, it supports extending your desktop over USB-c, but it only works if you have thunderbolt or DP alt mode on both of your laptops. Your monitors need both displayport and hdmi for it to work properly, because there is only one DP and the hdmis are mirrored. (I have not tested this, I do not use USB-c docking)

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that one. Hopefully it works, I'll give it a shot.